# Using type 'null' instead of int in Dictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I need to declare a dictionary with 100 keys and values (Key is a string and the value is an integer). Each of the keys will be a grid reference: A1, B6 etc. I know the definite values of some of the grids. I want to add a key and a value for every single value at the start of the program by setting the int values to null but it won't allow that. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: A Dictionary is not declared or instantiated with a size

Comment: You could use a [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) int

Answer (score 4):

Adding a '?' after the int makes it a nullable type

```
Dictionary<string, int?> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int?>();
```

Answer (score 4):

`null` is not a type, it is a value (for a reference), which every reference-type can be assigned to.

So if I read your post correctly you have this:

```
 Dictionary< String, Int32 > // or Dictionary<string,int>
```

Change it to `Int32?` (syntax-sugar for `Nullable<Int32>`). You can also use the `{ { key, value } }` syntax to initialise a dictionary instead of repetitively calling `.Add( key, value )`, as in my example below:

```
Dictionary< String, Int32? > dict = new Dictionary< String, Int32? > {
     { "A1", null },
     { "A2", null },
     { "A3", null },
     { "A4",   16 },
     { "A5",  123 },
     // etc
};
```